# http err content length mismatch node js

Tags: node.js, http

I have set up a RestFul Server using nodejs. This get api send a json object that has array of object. The size of array can be very large (>50,000). I am using mongoose. Here is the server side code

```
var mq = DeviceData.find().lean();
mq.then(function(data) {
    res.json({
        error: data && data.length > 0 ? false : true,
        carry: req.query.carry,
        data: data
    });
}, function(err) {
    next(err);
})
```

When Data Set is large i get **http content mismatch** in my chrome browser. My Node version is v8.4.0. DeviceData is mongoose schema object. For front end I am using **AngularJS**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your frontend lib sends wrong header `Content-Length` which doest not match your actual data.

Here info from spec:

> When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is
>   allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in
>   the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an
>   invalid length is received and detected.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html